# how to count 3g traffic in android mobile?

Tags: android, network-traffic

What I want to do is to count 3G traffic and WiFi traffic respectively. Now I know how to do with WiFi. Below is the source code for WiFi. By this way I can count WiFi traffic for all the android phones of all manufactures. But I haven't found a similar way for 3g. Does anyone know?

```
//to get wifi interface  
private static String getProp(String prop){
    String output = "";
    try{
        Class<?> sp = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperites");
        Method get = sp.getMethod("get",String.class);
        output = (String)get.invoke(null,prop);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}


//to get the traffic from system file
...
...
if (connectinTpe == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
    String wifiInterface = getProp("wifi.interface");
    if(wifiInterface == null || "".equals(wifiInterface)) wifiInterface = "eth0";
    rxFile = "/sys/class/net/" +wifiInterface+ "/statistics/rx_bytes";
    txFile = "/sys/class/net/" +wifiInterface+ "/statistics/tx_bytes";
}
...
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Starting from API level 8 (Android 2.2) there is a class [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) which provides what you need:

> Class that provides network traffic statistics. These statistics
>   include bytes transmitted and received and network packets transmitted
>   and received, over all interfaces, over the mobile interface, and on a
>   per-UID basis.

On the older versions you can use the approach you mentioned (i.e. reading file content of `/sys/class/net/...` files). [This blog post](http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2010/10/where-does-android-gets-its-traffic.html) contains an excellent mapping between `TrafficStats` methods and file locations. And [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4029186/648313) contains the source its author used to read those files values. According to it you should first try to read number from "`/sys/class/net/rmnet0/statistics/rx_bytes`" file (for "received bytes" value) and if it fails try "`/sys/class/net/ppp0/statistics/rx_bytes`" instead.

Answer (score 0):

to get the current type of connection you can use the TelephonyManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

first check if the device is connected to the default mobile data connection and then check the connection type:

```
    if (connectinTpe == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
    {
         TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         int curConnectionType = tm.getNetworkType();

         if(curConnectionType >= /*connection type you are looking for*/)
         {
             // do what you want
         }
    }
```

Comment: The author asked how to count 3G traffic, and not how to determine the current type of connection