# Trafficstats from specific application

Tags: android, network-programming

I'm trying to get the traffic generated by my application. It includes a video streaming and I want to get network usage data.

I've used TrafficStats with Mobile and Total function. Now I want to set it to work using the application UID but I haven't managed to do so, as it always returns -1. I'm using Android 2.3.4 and here is the code:

```
int uid = getApplication().getApplicationInfo().uid;
uid = android.os.Process.myUid();
long txApp = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
long rxApp = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid);
```

With both uids I get an error (-1) on TrafficStats. Any help?

Comment: Can you please share what was your mobile model ? I just want to see that how reliable TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes() is. Android docs also says that networkStats are not accessible in some phones.

Comment: I did all my developments with a Nexus S. I can try to look for more information but it's a project I finished 2 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your device does not support `TrafficStats`. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidTxBytes%28int%29) states:

> If the statistics are not supported by this device, UNSUPPORTED will be returned.

The code for `TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED` is `-1`.

You can instead read the `/sys/class/net/` log files. Try the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9472571/154306).

Comment: I forgot to put the answer. What so busy with the development. I did the way you say. Just as simple as reading a file ;)

Comment: @paul Is that condition is so rare ? Cant we check this feature availability from manifest ?