# TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(ProcessUID) randomly returns "-1"?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read out the traffic generated by the running applications. I pretty much want to get network usage data of every process.

TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(ProcessUID); would sometimes return the right result, but sometimes a "-1" would be returned. If I understand correctly, TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED is returned in the above cases, what I don´t understand is, why? I thought the UNSUPPORTED flag was meant to differ the ability of running device to fetch the data and was not bind in any way to a certain process.

```
        Integer ProcessUID = ProcessListData.get(i).getUID();
        Long RxBytes = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(ProcessUID);
        Long TxBytes = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(ProcessUID);
```

I am running Android 2.3.3. Thanks!

Comment: It seems a "-1" value is returned even if 0 RX/TX Bytes were received/sent through the respective app, not that big of a big deal actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"-1" means TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED**

See followin link, may be helpful for you

[Can someone explain how TrafficStats works its magic in the Android OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029186/can-someone-explain-how-trafficstats-works-its-magic-in-the-android-os/9472571#9472571)