# Android4.0.3, How can I get the value of  TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag()  without ddms?

Tags: android, network-traffic

In Android 4.0, Google supports `TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag()` to monitor the frequency of app data transfers, but I can just see it in DDMS.

How can I get the value of each tag and not use DDMS, so I can save it on the phone? How can DDMS get the value? Is it saved somewhere in system file?

Here is a question like this, but it is for API level 8 and only get the total value:
[Can someone explain how TrafficStats works its magic in the Android OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029186/can-someone-explain-how-trafficstats-works-its-magic-in-the-android-os/9472571#9472571)

here is googel explain the tag :http://source.android.com/tech/datausage/tags-explained.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i find the file store the value , it is "/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats".