# How Android TrafficStats class work?

Tags: android, monitoring, network-traffic

I'm not asking about implementation of `TrafficStats` in my app. I just wanna know how it works in the background. Is it monitoring the wifi clip or something to get the network traffic or just transmitting/downloading own bytes in every specific time to know the current network speed?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

"...just transmitting/downloading own bytes in every specific time to know the current network speed?", You don't get the network speed, you get the bytes sent/received. They are one of total/mobile/uid bytes. RTFM.

As for how it is done, in short, the (linux) kernel writes them in a special (proc) filesystem. They are available as readable files. The android framework reads it from those files. Here's a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029186/can-someone-explain-how-trafficstats-works-its-magic-in-the-android-os): and the source code for [TrafficStats](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-mr2-release/core/java/android/net/TrafficStats.java).